# C4430 error when using templates in VC++

Tags: c++, templates

I am not so experienced with C++ templates & run into problems. Perhaps, you can see the silly error I am doing. Thank you for your help!

Constants.h:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <io.h>
#include <sstream>

class Constants
{
public:
    [...]
    template<typedef const T>
    static CString ToString(T VALUE);
};
```

Constants.cpp:

```
template<typedef const T>
CString Constants::ToString(T VALUE)
{
    stringstream ss;

    ss << VALUE;

    CString csRow = ss.str().c_str();

    return csRow;
}
```

Comment: When you post questions on errors include the line number also

Answer (score 4):

For future reference on Stack Overflow, copy-and-paste any and all compiler errors verbatim, and point out the line numbers in your code snippets.

---

If you're new to C++, I highly, highly recommend that you [pick up a good introductory C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) and read it. The C++ tag wiki here has a list of books recommended by the C++ community here on Stack Overflow.

---

There are multiple issues with the code snippet you posted. Here's what I can see from visual inspection of the snippet:

Change `typedef const T` to `typename T` and move the definition into the header:

```
class Constants   
{   
public:
    [...]
    template<typename T> 
    static CString ToString(T value); 
    { 
        std::stringstream ss; // Note std:: prefix!
        ss << value; 
        CString csRow = ss.str().c_str(); 
        return csRow; 
    }
};
```

(You can also use `class T` instead of `typename T`; they are both equivalent in this case.)

Ensure that the compiler can see the definition of `CString`. [You may need to include `cstringt.h`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) if `stdafx.h` doesn't do that already.

Also note that the standard library types live in the `std` namespace. That's why there's a `std::stringstream` there instead of simply a `stringstream`. You could also use `using namespace std;`, but do not ever use it in a header file.

Avoid the use of `UPPERCASE NAMES` for variables and parameters; they are usually reserved for macros.

Comment: Thank you very much! With cstringt.h included, it runs now properly!

Answer (score 0):

```
C4430 C++ does not support default-int
```

Just check out the line in which error pops up and check to see if you have missed any type specifiers in variable declaration or fubctions

Answer (score 0):

Use typename or class instead of typedef